# Function to find marked-up text and replace it with code tags

Tags: php, html, function, tags

i made this function to find specific sets of characters in a text string and convert them to html tags:

```
function ccfc($content)
{
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    // $code_block =  preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=".$url[0].">{$url[0]}</a> ", $content);
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $content, $url)) {

           // make the urls hyper links
           $content = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=".$url[0].">{$url[0]}</a> ", $content);

    } else {

           // if no urls in the text just return the text
           $content = $content;

        }



    $code_block = preg_replace_callback(
          '/([\`]{3})(.*?)([\`]{3})/s',
          function($matches) {
              $matches[2] = htmlentities($matches[2]);
              return '<pre><code>'. $matches[2] .'</code></pre>';
          },
          $content);

      $bold = preg_replace_callback(
                  '/([\*]{2})(.*?)([\*]{2})/s',
                  function($matches) {
                      $matches[2] = htmlentities($matches[2]);
                      return '<b>'. $matches[2] .'</b>';
                  },
                  $code_block);

      $italic = preg_replace_callback(
                  '/([\*]{1})(.*?)([\*]{1})/s',
                  function($matches) {
                      $matches[2] = htmlentities($matches[2]);
                      return '<i>'. $matches[2] .'</i>';
                  },
                  $bold);


    return $italic;

}
```

This function will find the urls like http://www.google.com and convert them to links

the second will find the ``` code content ``` and convert it to `<pre><code> code content </code></pre>`
The third will find the ** content ** and convert to `<b> content </b>`
The fourth will find the * content * and convert it to `<i> content </i>`
but if the code is written outside the ``` ``` it is executed. How can I make the remaining text use htmlentities()?

Comment: The `<b>` and `<i>` tags are deprecated; you should put the text in a `<span>` or other tags and set a css class.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Or use `<strong>` and `<em>` if OP is trying to convey emphasis, which it seems like he's trying to do with markdown conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling `htmlentities` after running the text through your converter functions, call it before you do the converting:

```
function ccfc($content) {
    $content = htmlentities($content);
```

This won't affect the entities involved in the markup (`*` and `` ` ``), and you can also set the `double_encode` flag to false ensure that already-encoded content (e.g. `&` characters in links) does not get encoded twice -- [see the PHP manual for the settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
$content = htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES, UTF-8, false);
```

This setting will treat the text as UTF-8, encode all quotes, but will not double encode a link like `http://example.com?p=1&amp;q=2`.

On another note, you don't need to use `preg_replace_callback` for your substitutions; you can use the captured text in the replacement expression. Here's an example from the code formatting regex:

```
$code_block = preg_replace(
      '/`{3}(.*?)`{3}/s',
      "<pre><code>$1</code></pre>",
      $content);
```

As noted in my comment, `<b>` and `<i>` are deprecated; if you are using them to place emphasis on text, you could replace them with `<strong>` and `<em>` respectively; if the markup is solely for presentation, it is better to enclose the text in a `<span>` element and give it a class which has bold or italic formatting.

Here is the full code with the htmlentities moved and preg_replace replacements:

````
function ccfc($content)
{   $content = htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES, NULL, false);

    echo $content . PHP_EOL;

    $reg_exUrl = "/((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/?\S*)?)/";

    // $code_block =  preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href=".$url[0].">{$url[0]}</a> ", $content);
    // make the urls hyperlinks
    $content = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>", $content);

    # replace ``` with code blocks
    $content = preg_replace(
        '/`{3}(.*?)`{3}/s',
        "<pre><code>$1</code></pre>",
        $content);

    # replace **text** with strong text
    $content = preg_replace(
            '/\*{2}([^\*].*?)\*{2}/s',
            "<strong>$1</strong>",
            $content);

    # replace *text* with em text
    $content = preg_replace(
              '/\*(.*?)\*/s',
             "<em>$1</em>",
              $content);

    return $content;
}
````

A quick explanation of how `preg_replace` works: when you use parentheses in a regular expression, you capture the matter within those parentheses to the special variables $1, $2, $3, etc. The contents of the first set of parentheses are in `$1`, the contents of the second set in `$2`, and so on. For example, take this regular expression:

```
/(\w+) and (\w+)/
```

and the input string `bread and butter`, `bread` matches the expression in the first set of parens and `butter` matches the expression in the second set; `$1` would be set to `bread` and `$2` to butter. This becomes useful when we do `preg_replace`, as we can use `$1` and `$2` in the replacement string:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\w+) and (\w+)/", "I love $2 on $1", "bread and butter");
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
I love butter on bread
```

Anything that is in the match string but isn't captured will disappear -- like the `and` in this example.

In the replacements in your code, the text between the delimiters (`*` and `` ` ``) needs to be kept, so it is captured in parentheses; the delimiters themselves are not needed, so they aren't in parentheses.

Explanation of the other characters in the regexs:

- `?`, `*`, `+`, `{2}` : these are quantifiers - they dictate the number of times the preceding pattern should appear. `?` means 0 or 1 times; `*` is 0 or more times; `+` is one or more times; `{2}` means twice; `{500}` would mean 500 times.
- `\w` represents any number, letter, or `_`
- `.` matches any character
- `.*?` matches a string of any length, including length 0.
- `\**` would match 0 or more `*` characters; to match `*`, you have to escape it (i.e. `\*`) so that the regex engine doesn't interpret it as a quantifier

Comment: About the text i will make another function like this 
```$code_block = preg_replace(
      '/([\*]{3})(.*?)([\*]{3})/s',
      "<b><i>$2</i></b>",
      $content);
```
And for the links it is handled for more links i just tried it it is ok

Comment: @DiarSelimi You can actually handle `***` with your existing code if you're clever with your regular expressions. Try running some text through your function and see what comes out--there will be a problem with the output, but you can fix it with some regular expression cunningness.

Comment: i figured it out, i just put the italic function before the bold and change the variables to return the bold and it's good :)

Comment: @i alarmed alien No it is wrong if it is something to change here in the preg_replace then i don't know cause i don't really understand good this function and there is no good explanation for it, :(

Comment: @i alarmed alien , yeah i understand now those but what about those w+ / {} etc. mean ?

Comment: I've added some more about regexes to the answer